# WPF Image control masked with a container same as polygon

Tags: c#, wpf, image, button, transparency

I placed a **PNG Image with some transparent areas** on my window. It's **over a Button control**, now when i want to click on My Button, it has **some UnClickable points** because transparent space of image is over it.

**Now, i want mask my image with another control like polygon or use a good way to solve my problem.**

I tested following way, but it didn't fill all of the polygon area by image. It is like a rectangle image inside a polygon:

```
<Polygon
    Points="0 50,50 60,58 50,60 50,85 50,95 65,112 65,130,40135,40135 90,0 90"
    Stroke="Purple" 
    StrokeThickness="2" Margin="0,0,146,99" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="139" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Height="99">
            <Polygon.Fill>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Resources/myImage.png" AlignmentY="Top" Stretch="None" />
            </Polygon.Fill>
</Polygon>
```

**Result is like this:**
................................[image].............................

**But I want something like this:**

.....................[image].................

Comment: make your image square and use stretch="fill" or something.

Comment: @HighCore, thank you, i created a transparent imaged with 4 point in 4 corners of it, now every thing with my above solution (polygon filled by image) work well! please write your tip as an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the fill image of your polygon  **rectangular** and use `Stretch=None or Fill or...`.

Comment: I used a rectangular image with stretch=none for fill image of polygon and it work fine for me.